# Can you compare integer part of two fractions without division?

Tags: algorithms, numerics

Suppose we need to compare
$\left \lfloor{a / b}\right \rfloor $
and
$\left \lfloor{c / d}\right \rfloor $
.
One way would of course be to calculate $a/b$ and $c/d$ by division. Is their a faster way?

Comment: Are they positive?

Comment: Yes, all $a,b,c,d$ are positive.

Comment: Are you comparing for equality, or do you need the full three-way comparison?

Comment: Multiplication and adding/subtracting are allowed or not?

Comment: Comparing just for equality. Multiplication is faster than division so I guess that would be allowed. Adding subtracting is definitely allowed.

Comment: @SyedFahad Are all of $a, b, c, d$ integers? The question seems to imply it, but it does not say so. If they are integers, and $b$ and $d$ are constants (as opposed to run-time variable), any decent compiler with optimizations turned on should give you division code that is almost as fast as an integer division.

Comment: @njuffa Yes they are arbitrary precision integers, and hence compiler optimization will not apply

Answer (score 5):

A necessary condition for $\lfloor a/b\rfloor = \lfloor c/d\rfloor$ is $|ad-bc| < db$. This is not sufficient however, so if this test yields *true* (or if one of the multiplications overflows), you still must do the integer division. Depending on the probability distribution of your numbers *a,b,c,d* and the runtime complexity of multiplication compared to division, this can still be a runtime improvement on average.